# After migrating to Windsor 3 registering different implementations from xml and code for one interface is failing

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

We're in process of migrating one stable project from Castle Windsor 2.5.2 to 3.0.

We use mixed xml/api registration. After switching to 3.0, parameters injected through ctor and defined in xml can't be resolved anymore.

To illustrate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
...
  <properties>
    <frontEnd.url>http://site.com</frontEnd.url>
    <admin.email>admin@site.com</admin.email>
  </properties>

  <components>
    ...
    <component id="ServicesBootstrapperAction"
   service="SomeNS.Startup.IBootstrapperAction"
        type="SomeNS.Service.ServicesBootstrapperAction, Project-Service"
        >
      <parameters>
        <frontEndUrl>#{frontEnd.url}</frontEndUrl>
        <adminEmail>#{admin.email}</adminEmail>
        <prohibitedLogins>Assets/prohibited-logins.txt</prohibitedLogins>
      </parameters>
    </component>
    ...
  </components>
</configuration>
```

And the registration:

```
        _container.Install(
            Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromXmlFile("project.common.config"),
            Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromXmlFile(String.Format("project.{0}.config", RuntimeEnvironment))
            );
```

After trying to resolve this component we get:

```
'SomeNS.Service.ServicesBootstrapperAction' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Parameter 'frontEndUrl' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?
- Parameter 'adminEmail' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?
- Parameter 'prohibitedLogins' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?
```

Again, this is something that worked perfectly with 2.5 so I guess it might be some undocumented (or missed/not understood by us) breaking change.

Differential diagnosis, anyone?

UPDATE:
I figured out the problem and have found a workaround. I don't like it but it works.

For all curious, here's the link to the project illustrating the problem:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7XFrOzGfmirSldZUmRQeU9SZDZZVnV5UGhGaGhsUQ

Feel free to tell me that I'm wrong and that I should have used some other beautiful solution (what?).

Comment: Could you create a standalone failing test?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, I was going to. But then I've noticed one piece of code involving .Unless(), which stopped working but was still allowed somehow. Long story short, some services was registered twice and in runtime was chosen the last registered implementation. It's actually sad that Windsor allowed this kind of behavior. I still have 168 tests to fix. Then I'll get back to ranting.

Comment: Windsor uses the first registered service, not the last one, and it's not sad, it's useful and by design.

Comment: Somehow it was using the last one in our case (I've registered the xml before using api). But I was sad about Unless() acting like obsolete but still being a part of windsor api.

Comment: Again, post a standalone failing test and we'll see what's wrong :)

Comment: I will, first thing tomorrow morning. There's another case I have to investigate.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, sorry for delay, here's the link to solution: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7XFrOzGfmirSldZUmRQeU9SZDZZVnV5UGhGaGhsUQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's fair to close this issue since I've found a workaround for my original problem.

My true problem was that I had several implementations for one interface (and needed them all). But, some of the implementations required parameters (simple values) which naturally was moved to xml configuration file and other implementations were registered using conventions in code.

Now, to avoid double registrations I've used .Unless(container.Kernel.HasComponent) prior to 3.0, which is now supposedly obsolete, but compiled just fine!

Surprisingly, .Unless(t => container.Kernel.HasComponent(t.Name)) worked great as before!

I'm sure there's an explanation for this but I can't think of any.

I really love Castle and enjoy using it. But 45 kb of breaking changes is not cool, sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the periods from your node names.  It shouldn't matter, but that's the only thing I could see as a potential issue (mainly because, other than XAML, I haven't seen much use of periods in XML node names).

Comment: I've thought about it too, and have tried doing so, but without success.